# Can I use Flash builder 4.7 as eclipse mars.1 plugin?

Tags: java, eclipse, apache-flex, eclipse-plugin, flash-builder

I'm working with Flex SDK 3.2 since 2010 with Flex builder 3 with eclipse ganymed. Now I want tu use Flex SDK 4.6
 Cant I Open the workspace using a new Flash Builder plugin into new eclise mars.1 ?

Comment: There's a workaround where you can technically get the Flash builder plugin hooked into Eclipse Mars, but it doesn't work very well.  I gave up and went back to normal Flash Builder 4.7 because there were too many weird problems.

Comment: Ok so I have to use eclipse 3.7 32 bits with flash builder plugin 32 bit and java 32 bit also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this, sort of. I support a long running application that has it's front end in Flex and it's backend on JBoss/Oracle and we have to use this gimmick to keep the tools happy.

Since you have 3.7 installed with FlashBuilder 4.7 already installed, simply install (unzip)  Mars.1 somewhere else then copy the file fb-4_7-plugin-encoded.link like this:

```
cp C:\eclipse-juno-64\dropins\fb-4_7-plugin-encoded.link C:\eclipse-mars-64\dropins
```